# cordova record audio not work windows 10 mobile

Tags: windows, cordova, audio, cordova-plugins, audio-recording

I work for some time with the media cordova plugin on android and ios mobile on to record audio files. It works well. However on windows, while recording no error occurred, but no file exists. Just when the application goes into background and we return it, an error with code like 2147483648 (I have not found any information relevant to my problem with this code).

```
function recordAudio() {
var src = "ms-appdata:///temp/sound.m4a";;
var mediaRec = new Media(src,
    // success callback
    function() {
        console.log("recordAudio():Audio Success");
    },

    // error callback
    function(err) {
        console.log("recordAudio():Audio Error: "+ err.code);
    });

// Record audio
mediaRec.startRecord();
```

}

I can not find solutions or similar problems. The rest github does not included the problems.

Answer (score 0):

In MediaProxy.js (plugins/cordova-plugin-media/mediaProxy.js)
There is this constant:

```
var PARAMETER_IS_INCORRECT = -2147024809;
```

Is this the error you are getting? If so, this only seems to be used in one place, if there is no scheme for the path. Take a look at `setTemporaryFsByDefault()` in that same file.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, now I no longer work on WindowsPhone, however it appears that the error code is not the same, I have not yet found the solution but would try to quickly when I would use again WP